# Is there any way of merging two sets of tiles with gdal2tiles?

Tags: gdal, tiles, gdal2tiles

I've executed gdal2tiles against 2 raster coverages:

- One big raster coverage, composed by several TIFF files. Example of
  tile: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6599273/319.png
- One single TIFF file, geographically placed inside the coverage
  above, but that wasn't procesed in the previous step. Example of tile:
  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6599273/319_bis.png

So, I first executed gdal2tiles against a "puzzle" of TIFF files, with
a missing piece, and then I executed gdal2tiles against that single
missing piece. I want to merge both tiles set. Zoom levels were 4-14,
only Google Maps output. Only levels 4-12 have the problem (tiles with
the same coords).

Is there any way of merging tiles or should I execute gdal2tiles
against the whole "puzzle"?

Answer (score 3):

MapTiler could help here. I read on their [Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/maptiler/browse_thread/thread/245b4f568ce68037) that if you tiled that missing piece into the folder where the other tiles were already made, it'll merge the tiles nicely. .

If that doesn't work for you, but you have ImageMagick installed you can try the [script I wrote](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/474350/software/mergetilesets.pl) for the same purpose.

Comment: Great! I'm going to try the '-r antialias' option, like suggested. But anyway, I was coding a script like yours. So, many thanks!

Comment: The script is not available - dead link :/

Comment: @MadsSkjern Dropbox changed their filing system, it's still available but a different link now
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/9immqgig2gpt5u9wt89ec/mergetilesets.pl?rlkey=zbzgx8yf89elvdztaipdn99jv&dl=0

Answer (score 2):

I've never did it but it seems [gdal merge](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html)  could be appropriate :

> This utility will automatically mosaic a set of images. All the images must be in the same coordinate system and have a matching number of bands, but they may be overlapping, and at different resolutions. In areas of overlap, the last image will be copied over earlier ones.

Let us know!

Comment: Yes, I tested with gdal_merge, but the problem is some tiles contain part of the hole, and part of valid image. There's no simply some blank tiles representing the hole. Those tiles would be easily replaced by valid ones. Thanks for your suggestion, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I notice this is a rather old thread but I nevertheless have the same question I'm looking for an answer to. Would it be possible to share that script again? It seems that the dropbox link has stoped to work at this moment.

Thanks,
Stefan